# Принцип обновления файлов в Git

Tags: git

Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос. Допустим, два программиста работают с одним и тем же файлом, например index.html на своих локальных компьютерах. Работают независимо друг от друга и вносят разные изменения в файл. Потом первый программист загружает измененный файл на общий git хостинг (допустим, gitlab). Через некоторое время второй программист загружает свою версию файла на gitlab.

При этом оба программиста прогрузят свои версии файла в одну и ту же ветку, например в master.

Вопрос: какую версию файла мы в итоге увидим на gitlab?

Comment: Последнюю, которую добавили. История коммитов сохранится, и мы всегда сможем узнать, кто сломал приложуху :) [Тут](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2) всё подробно расписано.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Последней и главной будет 2 версия. Но при условии, что 2 программист перед тем, как залить код на мастер стянет последние изменения. Иначе при заливании будет коллизия. У меня так было. Забыла стянуть изменения и код не хотел заливаться.

Возможно,я не права и просто мне так "повезло" тогда. Но мой совет: чаще стягивать последние изменения с гита. И не заливать сразу на мастер,а иметь промежуточные ветки на каждый проект отдельную. Чтоб, при случае тотальной ошибки, можно было откатить назад 1 свою ветку,а не все изменения других людей.

Comment: То есть, если второй программист не стянет последнюю версию, после первого программиста, то свой измененный файл он не сможет прогрузить на сервер, верно?

Comment: Проверил, действительно это так.

Comment: Еще когда стягиваешь последнюю версию, редактор Atom выделяет все новое, чего не было в файле по сравненю с предыдущие версией. Вот скрин: https://paste.pics/5HWAA

Comment: Если изменить одну и ту же часть одного и того же файла по-разному в двух объединяемых ветках, Git не сможет их чисто объединить. Если исправление потребовало изменить ту же часть файла, получится  сообщение о конфликте слияния.
Git не создал коммит слияния автоматически. Он остановил процесс до тех пор, пока не разрешится конфликт.

Comment: Ок, понятно. Я правильно понимаю, что стараются делать так, чтобы один программист работал с одним файлом в одно время, чтобы не создавались вот такие конфликты с версиями?

Comment: @NikitaMigushev Нет, не правильно. В больших командах хоть и 100 человек могут работать с одним файлом в одно время, главное правильно конфликты решать..

Comment: @NikitaMigushev, это какой плагин Atom так выделяет конфликты?

Comment: @InDevX, в принципе, да. Но если 100 человек работают с один файлом, что-то с проектом не так. Если это класс, то по первому принципу **S**OLID, у класса может быть только одна причина на изменение, и сто человек уж точно не должны туда лазить. По стилям также, бьется на модули. В общем, я не могу придумать причину, чтобы сто человек полезли именно в этот файл.

Comment: @TotalPusher это был грубый, абстрактный пример... Мы в компании иногда делаем марафоны, то там бывает 2-3 человека с одним файлом работают одновременно. А на моей практике принципы не часто соблюдаются.. Пол года работаем над старым проектом (2011 года стартовал), его писали ещё тогдашние джуны, так что там не только принципами какими-то а местами даже логикой и не пахнет.. Но всё переписывать = тратить деньги + время.. 
А с файлом, простой вам пример - есть общие файлы, типа стилей и т.п.. - с ним могут и сотня работать, каждый над своими стилями

Comment: @TotalPusher Ничего специально не ставил. Работает с коробки